# schema of an existing table in JSON format using bigquery select statement in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Can we write select statement to get schema of an existing table in JSON format  or
can we write  bigquery to

Select statement should generate the json format in the result set.
(or in bigquery - how to Select existing table schema as JSON format)

example - [
{
"name": "year",
"type": "INTEGER",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "month",
"type": "INTEGER",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "project_bytes",
"type": "BYTES",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
"name": "lang",
"type": "STRING",
"mode": "NULLABLE"
}
]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metadata of datasets and tables and the columns can be accessed by a query.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro

For `yourdataset` all columns of all tables can be show with their schema:

```
SELECT * FROM yourdataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name="yourtablename"
```

Converting this into a JSON string is also possible:

```
Select table_name, TO_JSON_STRING(array_agg(schema_col)) schema
from (
SELECT
  table_name,column_name,
   STRUCT(T.column_name AS name,
    any_value(T.data_type) AS type,
    IF (any_Value(T.is_nullable)="YES","NULLABLE",null) AS mode
    ) as schema_col
FROM
  yourdataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T
GROUP BY
  1,  2
) group by 1
```

[image: query output]